# How to addchild two 'folder', one is point, the other is polygon

Tags: php, xml, directory, addchild

```
$kml = new SimpleXMLElement('<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"></kml>');

$kml->addChild('Document');
$kml->Document->addChild('Folder');
$kml->Document->addChild('Folder');
$kml->Document->addChild('Folder');
$kml->Document->Folder->addChild('name','a');
$kml->Document->Folder->addChild('name','b');
$kml->Document->Folder->addChild('name','c');
```

I want to use PHP to make a KML from XML
but only show folder a in Google Earth. I need to show three folders in a web folder
like:

↓口poly (web folder)

```
↓口a (folder)
    →point1
    →point2
↓口b (folder)
    →polygon1
    →polygon2
↓口c (folder)
    →polyline1
    →polyline2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$kml->Document->addChild('Folder');
$kml->Document->Folder->addChild('name','a');
$kml->Document->addChild('Folder');
$kml->Document->Folder[1]->addChild('name','b');
$kml->Document->addChild('Folder');
$kml->Document->Folder[2]->addChild('name','c');
```

it`s work

thx everyone